# User Registration in OpenCms

Tags: jsp, servlets, opencms

I am new in **OpenCms** and I want to create a new user with java source. I had written the following code, but its not working. What is the proper procedure to make a new user.

***"Output Error":***

> Admin org.opencms.security.CmsSecurityException: Error adding the user
>   "John".

Source Code

---

```
<%@ page session="true" import="org.opencms.main.*, org.opencms.jsp.*,org.opencms.file.*, java.lang.String " %>
<%

    CmsJspActionElement cms = new CmsJspActionElement(pageContext,request,response);
    CmsObject cmsObject = OpenCms.initCmsObject(OpenCms.getDefaultUsers().getUserGuest());
//  CmsObject cmsObject = cms.getCmsObject();
    cmsObject.loginUser("Admin", "admin");

    session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session!=null){
        session.invalidate();
    }
    session = request.getSession(true);

    cmsObject.getRequestContext().setCurrentProject(cmsObject.readProject("Offline"));
    cmsObject.getRequestContext().setSiteRoot("/sites/default/");

    try{
        out.print("<br/>"+cmsObject.getRequestContext().getCurrentUser().getName());
        CmsUser user = cmsObject.createUser("John","123","Programmical Instructions", null);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        out.print("<br/>"+ex);
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a module to do that, have you try it? 

opencms 8 http://www.alkacon.com/en/modules/downloads/oamp-webuser_2.0.0.html

opencms 7 http://www.alkacon.com/en/modules/downloads/oamp-webuser-0.9.0.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 arguments in `CreateUser` method in 'CmsObject' class:

```
CmsUser createUser(String name, String password, String description, Map<String, Object> additionalInfos);
```

And Password at lest 4 characters. That's required in OpenCms System. You should change password: 1234

```
CmsUser user = cmsObject.createUser("John","1234","Programmical Instructions", null);
```